# Erro configurar Mysql no xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

Estou configurando o `XAMPP v3.2.2` e o meu `MySQL` não está funcionando, segue o ***erro***:

> `Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.`
>
> 5:46:11 PM  [mysql]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
>
> 5:46:11 PM  [mysql]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
>
> 5:46:11 PM  [mysql]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
>
> 5:46:11 PM  [mysql]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
>
> 5:46:11 PM  [mysql]    If you need more help, copy and post this
>
> 5:46:11 PM  [mysql]    entire log window on the forums

As soluções encontradas na Internet se resumem a apagar o arquivo ibdata1 no diretório `xampp/mysql/data`. Essa solução não funcionou, pois eu excluo o arquivo e executo o `MySQL` no `Control Panel` do `Xampp` ele cria esse arquivo novamente.

E a outra solução seria alterar a porta que por padrão é **3306**, foi alterada para **3307**, mas sem sucesso também.

Alguém teria mais alguma possível solução?

Comment: Veja se o Skype não está utilizando a porta 80, ele costuma travar o xampp. Em último caso, apague o xampp e tente reinstalar a última [versão do site](https://www.apachefriends.org/pt_br/index.html):

Comment: Não tenho o skype instalado. Vou reinstalar o XAMPP e volto a comentar. Obrigado.

Comment: Não esqueça de fazer backup do `htdocs`.

Answer (score 0):

Olá recentemente tive o mesmo problema. Segue abaixo a solução para resolver:

1. Sair do Xampp;
2. Acesse o diretório de sua instalação entre na Pasta data,(Padrão: C:\xampp\mysql\data);
3. Selecione todos os arquivos: aria_log, ib_buffer, ib_logfile, ibdata1, master-xxxx@xxx, multi-master, mysql_error, mysql-relay-bin-2019@, relay-log-xxxx@ (**Menos as Pastas onde estão os bds e o arquivo my** (**configuração do mysql**)), exclua todos; 
   Obs: O x representa o que está no seu pc, podendo ser data ou outra escrita.
4. Reinicie o PC;
5. Após logar, é só abrir o Xampp normalmente. Só ai poderá excluir todos os arquivos da lixeira.

Qualquer dúvida só retornar ok! No que for possível irei ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, resolvi indo no icone do Mysql Notifier e dando stop.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]